# PHP - Search bar using two dropdown boxes

Tags: php

I have two dropdown forms that pull data from the database, one for the service and another for the town. The code works with one keyword $k but I'm not sure how to get search for both the town ($t) and service ($k).

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" style="margin:0 auto; text-align:center;" id="the-basics" onsubmit=submitForm(this)>

                   <select id="cd" name="k" class="search-left rounded-left">

                        <?php
                        $mysqlserver="localhost";
                        $mysqlusername="";
                        $mysqlpassword="";
                        $link=mysql_connect(localhost, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());

                        $dbname = '';
                        mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());

                        $cdquery="SELECT * FROM clients";
                        $cdresult=mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from clients failed: ".mysql_error());

                        while ($cdrow=mysql_fetch_array($cdresult)) {
                        $company_services=$cdrow["company_services"];

                            echo "<option>$company_services</option>";

                        }?>

                    </select>

                    <select id="cd" name="t" class="search-left rounded-left">

                        <?php

                        $mysqlserver="localhost";
                        $mysqlusername="";
                        $mysqlpassword="";
                        $link=mysql_connect(localhost, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());

                        $dbname = '';
                        mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());

                        $cdquery="SELECT * FROM clients";
                        $cdresult=mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from clients failed: ".mysql_error());

                        while ($cdrow=mysql_fetch_array($cdresult)) {
                        $town=$cdrow["town"];

                            echo "<option>$town</option>";

                        } ?>

                    </select>

                  <input type="submit" value="Search">

                </form>

                    $k = $_GET['k'];
                    $t = $_GET['t'];

                    $i = 0;
                    $terms = explode(" ", $k);
                    $terms = explode(" ", $t);

                    $query ="SELECT * FROM clients WHERE ";

                    foreach ($terms as $each) {
                        $i++;
                        if ($i == 1)
                            $query .= "company_services LIKE '%$each%'" . "OR town LIKE '%$each%'";
                    }
                    $dbconnect=@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
                    $db = mysql_select_db('');

                    $query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if ($numrows > 0){

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        /* show result here */
```

---

### Edited Code

```
                $k = $_GET['k'];
                $t = $_GET['t'];

                $i = 0;
                $term1 = explode(" ", $k);
                $term2 = explode(" ", $t);

                $result = array_merge($term1, $term2);

                $query ="SELECT * FROM clients WHERE "; 

                foreach ($result as $each) {
                    $i++;
                    if ($i == 1)
                        $query .= "company_services LIKE '%$each%'" . "OR town LIKE '%$each%'";
                }
                $dbconnect=@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
                $db = mysql_select_db('db_name');

                $query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if ($numrows > 0){

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

you're over writing `$terms`

do this instead and give it a go (btw that for loop is suspect big time as well, consider what you're trying to achieve)

change:

```
$terms = explode(" ", $k);
$terms = explode(" ", $t);
```

to:

```
$terms: [];
array_push($terms, explode(' ', $k));
array_push($terms, explode(' ', $t));
```

caveat is this will give you a nested array, `$terms[0]` will be an array of `$k` values, while `terms[1]` will be an array of `$t` values. Look into `array_merge` if you just want one big flat array

Comment: I have made the change but now I am getting a 500 Error. I'm new to PHP.

Comment: I have posted my updated code, your code you posted didn't seem to work I think my updated code is still only using one term.